# what is the location of the log file for bugzilla on windows

Tags: windows, bugzilla, smtp-auth

We are using Bugzlla on windows. We set up the SMTP server configuration in the admin parameters. But Bugzilla is unable to send emails. It always reports "Could not authenticate user". How to know the details of the error? Everything we configured are working fine when used in another system. Can you please point out the location of the log file

Any points to troubleshoot the issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Apache, check the Apache log directory for the error log.

If you're only having problems sending emails and you're getting authentication issues, the most probable cause for this is that your SMTP server requires authentication before it will let the server use it as a relay.

Try setting the `smtp_username` and `smtp_password` settings in Bugzilla.

There's also an `smtp_debug` setting in Bugzilla which will dump more verbose debugging information to the error log.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using Bugzilla on windows. smtp_username and smtp_password were set properly in Bugzilla. In spite of this, it gives the same error. I saw the error log, it only contains the env variables which are correct. Any further thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: double check that the credentials still work (use an email client), and check your smtp server's logs.  you could also use the 'sendmail' method, and use glob.com.au/sendmail with debugging enabled.  that'll tell me exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

For more control I installed [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) and didn't use the smtp_username at all and set smtpserver to localhost.